# How to remote validation with Asp.Net MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I Create this class.

```
  public class UniqueFileNumber : ValidationAttribute
    {

        private string _LocationFile;

        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string str)
        {
            return ViewRes.ValidationString.Loc_FileNumberExist;
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            DBEntities _db = EntityFactory.GetEntity();
            string strName = Convert.ToString(value);
            return !_db.Locations.Any(p => p.LocationFile == strName);

        }
    }
```

and add this attribute to my entity Like that.

```
[UniqueFileNumber]
public object FileNumber{ get; set; }
```

The validation work only on the PostBack (Refresh).

It would be fine if it's work on client side too. In my client side , I add that line

```
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
```

What's the problem here.

thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code that makes up your view as well? (Everything looks fine so far.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give it the javascript fonction to use for validation...

check out this post from Phil Haacked [ASP.NET MVC 2 Custom Validation](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx)

A better example for what you have to do since you still need to go on the server, check 
this post from Brad Wilson [Remote Validation with ASP.NET MVC 2](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/remote-validation-with-aspnet-mvc-2.html)

Comment: merci moi_meme, c'est exactement ce que je voulais :)

Comment: @Jean-François: Ça fait plaisir :)

Answer (score 0):

One more [Remote Validation ASP.NET MVC 2](http://blog.pocheptsov.com/2011/02/remote-validation-in-aspnet-mvc-2-with.html) based on Brad Wilson idea, but used jQuery ajax calls.